# Vim how to add a hash tag to an eruby (erb) file in order to comment out a line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vim

I'm still learning macvim and I love it but I haven't figured this out. So, say I have a rails or ruby view file and I want to comment out a line or multiple lines like this

```
post.html.erb

<span class="timestamp">
  <%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %>
  <%= post.created_at %>
</span>
```

In order to comment out the lines, add a hash tag after the percentage sign. This will comment out the line

```
<span class="timestamp">
  <%#= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %>
  <%#= post.created_at %>
</span>
```

The nerd commenter plugin will let you visually select the line(s) and `<leader> cc` will add comments but it wrong. It does this

```
<%#<%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %>%> 
<%#<%= post.created_at %>%>
```

it adds another set of `<%# %>` around the originals and the closing tags will show up in the view.

I want it to look like this

```
<%#= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %>
<%#= post.created_at %>
```

So the real question is how to map a command that will insert only the hash tag after the percentage sign on visually selected line(s)?

Comment: [tcomment](https://github.com/tomtom/tcomment_vim) handles this automatically :-)

Comment: Vim is extremely powerful and, as a result, is quite complex. It's usable right away, but there's deep magic to be learned. I highly recommend regularly looking through the `:h` help files and browse/read/try things. Also, search on Stack Overflow for the [tag:vim] tag and see what interesting things you'll dig up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment:

```
xnoremap <leader>c :s/^\s*<%/&#<CR>
nnoremap <leader>c :s/^\s*<%/&#<CR>
```

Uncomment:

```
xnoremap <leader>C :s/\(^\s*<%\)#/\1
nnoremap <leader>C :s/\(^\s*<%\)#/\1
```

Comment: Thank you for the mapped commands. They work great but something strange happens. every line on the page that has `<%=` is highlighted after I executed the command. Even the lines that I didn't select to be commented out. The highlights just stay there. Any idea on how to prevent this?

Comment: I appended this `<esc> :noh<return><esc>` to the end of the commands. It works. Thanks for the help

Comment: Sorry, I dislike `hlsearch` so it's always disabled here.

Comment: No worries. I'll look into disabling the highlights. They seem to just be a distraction. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When you have selected the lines in visual mode, you can enter command mode (:) and enter `s/<%=/<%#=/`. Binding that command to a custom shortcut would do it ?

Comment: ah, I didn't know how to search the percent sign and append after it in the same command. This is good. I'll try it.